# Calling methods in window forms

Tags: c#

By running my code i am getting this error
**Method must have a return type**.
 Its in my public withdraw method at the bottom. I may not be understanding this correctly, but I thought my return would be okay since my accessor and mutator methods are doing such. Also, I feel like since I using aMtBox.Text = a.withdraw(withdraw); that its not going to cast it correctly(or going to be needed to be casted?). I don't have an error about it yet but I am guessing its because I have not got past the return problem.

So, in a simpler way, how can I call my withdraw method to be used correctly in my withdraw_Click.

**My Main form code is as below**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        BankAccount a = new BankAccount();

        public void withdrawl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            aMtBox.Text = a.withdraw(withdraw);
        }
    }
}
```

**And My code for BankAccount is as below**

```
public class BankAccount
{
    decimal num1;
    decimal iBa;
    decimal total;

    public decimal IBa
    {
        set { iBa = value; }
        get { return iBa; }
    }
    public decimal Num1
    {
        set { num1 = value; }
        get { return num1; }
    }
    public decimal Total
    {
        set { total = value; }
        get { return total; }
    }
    public decimal withdraw(decimal withdraw)
    {
        num1 = 0.00m;
        iBa = 300.00m;
        total = iBa - num1;
        return total;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is with draw meant to return to assign to the text property total.tostring() ?

Comment: Code is very hard to read, put BankAccount in it's own file. (make it internal maybe, then perhaps the error will become apparent.

Answer (score 2):

this method must have return type

```
public withdraw(decimal withdraw)
        {
            num1 = 0.00m;
            iBa = 300.00m;
            total = iBa - num1;
        }
```

like

```
public decimal withdraw(decimal withdraw)
        {
            num1 = 0.00m;
            iBa = 300.00m;
            total = iBa - num1;
            return total;//or whatever
        }
```

Comment: aMtBox.Text = a.withdraw(withdraw); says does not exist in the current context. I had code similar to yours earlier. Can you explain what visual studios is trying to tell me?

Comment: what is 'withdraw' here that passed in method? like a.withdraw(variable), is that variable and is that exists? otherwise, add type of method and try again. otherwise post all code .

Comment: I modified my original code and made note of the problem for clearer undersanding

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error **Method must have a return type** because you do not have return type of

```
public withdraw(decimal withdraw)
    {
        num1 = 0.00m;
        iBa = 300.00m;
        total = iBa - num1;
    }
```

Now, as you know the problem you can fix it by giving return type to it,
Now question is which return type will you give `string` or `decimal`**?** 
My advice is to use decimal and then try to convert it in string while you assign it to
any string property like here you do `aMtBox.Text = a.withdraw(withdraw);`

---

Your code will look like

```
    public decimal withdraw(decimal withdraw)
    {
        num1 = 0.00m;
        iBa = 300.00m;
        total = iBa - num1;
        return total;
    }
```

and while you getting it use `aMtBox.Text = a.withdraw(withdraw).ToString();`
**Edit**
Do not forget to declare variable withdraw in your code

Your code will look like

```
Decimal withdraw = 100; 
aMtBox.Text = a.withdraw(withdraw).ToString();
```

---

@As asked in comment i am writing this code it is not part of original answer

```
 /// <summary>
 /// Called when user change textbox value
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="sender">Represent object of sender (i.e text box itself)</param>
 /// <param name="e">Reesent eventArgs</param>
 private void withBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox tmpTextBox = (TextBox)sender; // Doing type casting sender to textbox so that we can access property of it.
            decimal withdraw;
            bool bIsParsed = Decimal.TryParse(tmpTextBox.Text, out withdraw); // TryParse method return false if there is any problem in process of doing parsing of string to decimal
            if (!bIsParsed)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid number");
            }
        }
```

Comment: aMtBox.Text = a.withdraw(withdraw).ToString(); the (withdraw) does not exist in current context. I am trying to read an article on google to figure this out as well... Im sure its something small.

Comment: Have you define that veritable ? (withdraw)

Comment: well, I am wanting the variable to be whatever the user types in the private void withBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {} Its a textbox on my form

Comment: You know how to get that value using sender ?